# Why does ping need to be restarted after connection is restored

Tags: linux, networking, ping, kernel

My laptop is running Fedora 25 (kernel 4.9.5) over a wireless connection. Sometimes my xDSL line drops and gets reestablished. I usually leave ping running and it shows this:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=294 ttl=48 time=79.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=295 ttl=48 time=77.9 ms
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=307 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=308 Destination Net Unreachable
```

What's puzzling is that it continues like this forever until I restart ping:

```
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=730 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=731 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.5.1 icmp_seq=732 Destination Net Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10181 packets transmitted, 269 received, +154 errors, 97% packet loss, time 10414884ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 76.417/84.643/271.002/20.913 ms
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=103 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=93.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=85.5 ms
```

It seems ping is keeping some state that needs to be refreshed. What could it be?

**UPDATE**

```
... xDSL is down
11:10:29.261358 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 110, length 64
11:10:30.285354 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 111, length 64
11:10:31.309315 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 112, length 64
11:10:32.028919 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4382, seq 1, length 64

<<<<< ctrl-c ping, start ping again >>>>>

11:10:32.102610 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 4382, seq 1, length 64
11:10:33.030808 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4382, seq 2, length 64
11:10:33.113878 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 4382, seq 2, length 64
11:10:34.032032 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4382, seq 3, length 64
11:10:34.108532 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 4382, seq 3, length 64
11:10:35.033693 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4382, seq 4, length 64
11:10:35.111347 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 4382, seq 4, length 64
11:10:36.035507 IP 10.0.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4382, seq 5, length 64
11:10:36.111723 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 4382, seq 5, length 64
^C
```

Comment: What is `192.168.5.1`?

Comment: The local gateway

Comment: If you can, check with `tcpdump` (and Wireshark to view it) for differences before and after restarting the command. Because each echo request is standalone, there shouldn’t be any difference, except perhaps the echo request contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is most likely with the gateway, not your laptop. Even though the ping fails, you are getting an ICMP response from the gateway saying Destination Net Unreachable. It is the gateway that is no longer trying to forward your ping packets.

The gateway seems to reset when you restart your ping, suggesting it is somehow keeping state based on the sequence number in your ICMP echo requests. You may be able to avoid this by using UDP to ping.